# DefaultTreeModel and Wicket Tree: setAsksAllowsChildren doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, wicket, jtree

I'm using Wicket's Tree component in a web app. But empty folders are shown in a file-way.
Just like this:
[image]

Bellow is where I use the DefaultTreeModel and Tree:

```
PDMinterface pdmI = new PDMinterface(); 
DefaultMutabletreeNode rootTreeNode = pdmI.getDocTree();            //文档树根结点,由PDM接口提供
DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootTreeNode);
treeModel.setAsksAllowsChildren(true);
```

and I'm sure that folder5 is set to allow children:

```
public DefaultMutableTreeNode getDocTree(){  
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
    root.setAllowsChildren(true);
    FolderNode rootFolder = new FolderNode(0, "root", "Jiajun", true);
    root.setUserObject(rootFolder);

    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode newnode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        newnode.setAllowsChildren(true);
        FolderNode newFolder = new FolderNode(i+1, "Folder" + Integer.toString(i+1), "Jiajun", false);
        newnode.setUserObject(newFolder);
        root.add(newnode);
        if(i < 4){
            for(int j=0; j < 5; j++){
                DefaultMutableTreeNode newdocNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
                newdocNode.setAllowsChildren(false);
                DocNode newDoc = new DocNode(10*(i+1) + j, "Document" + Integer.toString(10*(i+1)+j), "Jiajun");
                newdocNode.setUserObject(newDoc);
                newnode.add(newdocNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will sound a little bit strange, but I have often had to extend some wicket components and adjust their code so it does exactly what I need. Have you tried looking into the source code of the components and see where they set the file / folder icon? They have often quite clean code and you can easily extend and override the method that's not doing what you want so you can get the features or L&F needed...

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I would try.

Comment: I added a reply where I think I found the cause and a way around, but you will have to elaborate on it and test it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more helpful than in my comment, I found this code in the AbstractTreeClass which will control what image it assigns to the node:

```
/**
 * Returns the resource reference for icon of specified tree node.
 *
 * @param node
 *            The node
 * @return The package resource reference
 */
protected ResourceReference getNodeIcon(TreeNode node)
{
    if (node.isLeaf() == true)
    {
        return getItem();
    }
    else
    {
        if (isNodeExpanded(node))
        {
            return getFolderOpen();
        }
        else
        {
            return getFolderClosed();
        }
    }
}
```

So, the whole thing comes to the question of what does the isLeaf() method return. I found this in the DefaultMutableTreeNode class:

```
public boolean isLeaf()
{
    return children.size() == 0;
}
```

So, it seems that your combination would treat all elements without children as leafs and not as folders. Maybe you could overwrite the getNodeIcon method using the getAllowsChildren, making  the necessary type adjustments...

Another idea is to overwrite the isLeaf() method of DefaultMutableTreeNode, but then you might get other unexpected issues if it is called somewhere you cannot control...

This is just some insight on how you could do it... Hope it is helpful...

Answer (score 2):

Which Wicket version are you using? The old tree implementation is deprecated in 6.x and removed in 7.x, so you should use the new implementation in package org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.tree - it is no longer based on the Swing classes.

Comment: I'm using 6.x and I have to use it, because I'm doing a cooperative project. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Coming into this topic of conversion of a project using Wicket 1.5 now trying to go to Wicket 8.8, the amount of help and information of changes to be made is less than encouraging.  The new tree classes are dropped in our laps and apart from mentions in the Migrations and the barely useful 'examples', this is not a pretty task.  Swing was left behind but not really.  It sits in many places including 'experimental' TreeModelProvider<T>.  Appreciate what Sven has done here, but its really a slog making this leap.  Example conversions from 6.x to 7.x would really help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line `if(i < 4){` in the outer `for` loop. You allow the node to have children but you don't create any children for this last node.

Edit: You are correct about the empty folder so my answer is incorrect. In Swing this works as expected. When the tree row is rendered the decision to draw a folder or file icon is based upon the flag `setAsksAllowsChildren`. So the problem seems to be on Wicket's tree component

Comment: Yes, it is a folder but empty, and an empty folder should look like a folder not like a file.

Comment: @Friedmannn You are correct. I have updated my answer to mention it is not correct. In Swing this works as expected. Perhaps you should add to your question what version you use and any code related to initialization of the involved components to increase the possibility that someone helps you out

Comment: I think it might be wicket's `Tree`'s problem. I just did an experiment in Swing and it's worked fine. Now I just wonder if where is an alternative for `Tree` since it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can override Folder.getStyleClass to return the desired Icon. I got something like this:

```
@Override
protected String getStyleClass() {
    String styleClass;
    if (isFolder(getModelObject()))
        {
            if (tree.getState(matter) == State.EXPANDED)
                 {
                     styleClass = getOpenStyleClass();
                 } else {
                     styleClass = getClosedStyleClass();
                 }
             } else {
                 styleClass = getOtherStyleClass(matter);
             }

             if (isSelected()) {
                 styleClass += " " + getSelectedStyleClass();
             }

             return styleClass;
        }
```

Your implementation of isFolder() may vary.