# Wicket: Is there an alternative for org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.tree since it's deprecated

Tags: java, swing, wicket

I'm using wicket and meet a problem with `Tree`. [DefaultTreeModel and Wicket Tree: setAsksAllowsChildren does't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809452/defaulttreemodel-and-wicket-tree-setasksallowschildren-doest-work)

Now I wonder what can I use instead of `Tree`?

Comment: Please update your original question on this topic: [DefaultTreeModel and Wicket Tree: setAsksAllowsChildren does't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809452/defaulttreemodel-and-wicket-tree-setasksallowschildren-doest-work)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Wicket 6 you can use the new tree implementation in the `org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.tree` package.

It does not use Swing anymore.

You could use `TableTree` or `DefaultTableTree`.

They both use a `ITreeProvider` for getting the data that works "almost" like the provider for the DataTable.